# Reverting ::selection pseudo CSS to default

Tags: css

Ho there, I have a piece of code where there is a ::selection defined. This code must stay.

```
::selection {background-color:red;}
```

Now, what I want to do is to revert the ::selection to its defaul value as defined by the user agent.

I have tried using values such as initial and inherit. They don't work as initial's value is transparent and there is no inherit value.

So I was wondering how I would be able to achieve the default selection as defined by the user agent.

Comment: Cant you  just remove it ?

Comment: I need the ::selection in there for separate pages and elements

Comment: can you set background-color to 'auto'?

Comment: auto is a good idea, although it just reverts it back to the first ::selection that I defined

Comment: @ThomasE.  ok then, i don't understand what you need then ...

Comment: @ThomasE. short of removing it or hard-coding a default color it does not seem as though much can be done...

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunate. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the selection value globally set it to the specific element you need. All other elements will then have the default selection. Selection only works with three values: color, background, text-shadow.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/

Answer (score 0):

set background-color to 'auto', so:

```
::selection {
    background-color:auto!important;
}
```

Comment: auto is a good idea, although it just reverts it back to the first ::selection that I defined, ie. the selection will be red

Comment: I think this should do it - tested on chrome and works, background-color reverts back to default blue.

Comment: On my chrome, it says that auto is an invalid value for background-color